# index.html to root in java(web.xml?)

Tags: java, html, redirect, web.xml

I have been searching for the answers for hours and all of the answers were using .htaccess in PHP.

However, I am developing this in java EE, and I was wondering if there is a way of doing what I describe below without using any libraries such as UrlRewriterFilter.

Ok.. So when a user get to   www.mywebsite.com/index.html , I want the url to be seen as  www.mywebsite.com

live example might be www.yahoo.com/index.html and the page redirects it to www.yahoo.com

Right now, when I type www.mywebsite.com,  i can see the index.html without that in the link, but if a user types www.mywebsite.com/index.html in the browser it stays that way in url.

I tried this in web.xml:  but it was a no-go

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>welcome</servlet-name>
    <jsp-file>/</jsp-file>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>welcome</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/index.html</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing this is in the servlet use

```
'response.sendRedirect("protocol://www.mysite.com");'
```

however, I would not think this is a recommended way as the HTTP Request is sent back to the client and then back to the server, instead I would try

I would instead try,

```
request.forward();
```

*The syntax above is not proper*

forward API operates differently, its an internal server redirect and the request is not sent back to the client.

http://www.javatpoint.com/sendRedirect()-method has some information not sure how in depth this is. Using servlet filters is another way of achieving the same thing but looks like it might be an overkill, if the URL re-write is the only thing you are trying to achieve. Hope this helps, but this might not be the best solution.

Comment: Thanks alot! I will take a look into this route and let you know the result later.